# How to determine client certificate type using Python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, client-certificates, pyopenssl

I have an HTTP-triggered Python Azure Function. The App Service which hosts this Function is set to `Require` Client Certs and only use HTTPS.

Azure automagically passes the client cert from each HTTP request to the Function code via the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header.

How do I determine the type (.der, .crt, .pem, .cer) of the incoming certificate using Python?

**Example:**

- When testing using Postman, I upload a cert in .crt format via `Settings/Certificates`
- Postman encodes this as a .der (binary) file and passes it to the Function endpoint
- Azure (load balancer?) receives the request and forwards the cert to my Python Function code via the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header

  - Azure will not alter the cert from its original form(?)
  - If client was using say, Python instead of Postman to generate the request and they sent a .pem file across the wire (rather than a .der file), the Function would receive a .pem file.

**How can I determine the cert file type so I can programmatically parse out the properties (`Issuer`, `Common Name`, `not_valid_before/after`, etc.) from the file?**

Comment: The service will really take any kind of cert?  I've never come across that.  I've done a fair amount of this sort of thing, but the server always expected a certain type of cert to come over the wire.  So, of course, in that case you don't have to figure out what kind of cert you have...you already know.

Comment: Hm. This is my first rodeo so if I'm mistaken, I'd like to know where/how. When I say different "types" of certs, I'm speaking about certs with different extensions (.pem, .crt, .der, .cer). If i'm not mistaken, these extensions indicate different encoding (.pem = base64, .der = base64+binary, etc.). I'm looking for a way to determine the encoding in Python and parse out the properties accordingly. I think @DorisLv's method below will suffice.

Comment: Yes, try that method.  I guess all I'm saying is that if you figure out the type once, you may very well always see only that one type.  If that's the case, and it turns out to be problematic to figure it out on the fly, you could just figure out the type manually and try using that all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't determine the cert automatically with python, but you can do it manually and view the encoded certification directly.

**Firstly**, open the certificate file with txt format, if there is a start line like `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----`, it is in `PEM` format, otherwise it is in `DER` format.

**Then**, here is some [common OpenSSL certificate manipulations](https://support.ssl.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19):

View PEM encoded certificate
Use the command that has the extension of your certificate replacing cert.xxx with the name of your certificate

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text -noout
openssl x509 -in cert.cer -text -noout
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout
```

If you get the folowing error it means that you are trying to view a DER encoded certifciate and need to use the commands in the “View DER encoded certificate  below”

unable to load certificate
12626:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
View DER encoded Certificate

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.der -inform der -text -noout
```

Comment: Thank you @DorisLv. I will determine if the first char of the cert is "-". If it is, I'll assume .pem if not, I'll assume .der and process/decode accordingly.